# Use PreChatObjects from liveAgent in Einstein Bot

Tags: liveagent, einstein, pre-chat, bots

I have a LiveAgent chat configured for iOS and Android devices, we send some informations like `UserName`, `Email`, `PhoneNumber` etc. using [PrechatObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.service_sdk_ios.meta/service_sdk_ios/live_agent_custom_data.htm). I am now building an Einstein bot, and I need to access some of those informations, but I don't know how.

I tried to specify an Variable, and use `{!VariableName}`, but it does print `{!VariableName}`

Comment: same here with pre-chat page on snap-in...I'm missing something but I don't actually get what!

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else get to this post...

I had the same issue and this is all explained here in the official cookbook
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_greet_customer_lex.htm

It worked for me.

Quick summary:

1. Create the fields you need to access in the LiveChatTranscript objects
2. Create variables in the bot for the same
3. Update the embedded chat settings extraPrechatFormDetails
4. Create context variable in the bot using ant or apex to retrieve the same
5. Set variables in the bot